# Where are all of the wizard colleges in Golarion?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, wizard, golarion

I am planning on creating a wizard character for the Wrath of the Righteous campaign but haven't been able to find any information on where exactly someone would go in the world to study being a wizard.

**Would a wizard's college be something that every major city would have to at least a certain degree?**

**If not in a major city, where are they all located?**

Comment: Is wizardry taught only in colleges in Golarion? Or is the master-apprentice system also present?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can assume that any **Large City** (population 10.000-25000) or larger city should have a magical academy, but most of them arent famous enough to be worth noting. Most academies become famous due to their students becoming celebrities as powerful mages themselves.

Most known *Capitals* do have the **academic** settlement quality, which means the city has a place of study of some sort, magical or not.

According to [PathfinderWiki.com](http://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Magic) on the subject of *Magic Schools*, we have the following:

### **Abjuration**

> **The Acadamae**, the premier magical college of the Varisian city of Korvosa, holds an annual event called the Breaching Festival.
>
> Abjuration is also one of the chief focuses of study at the **Stone of the Seers**, **Magnimar**'s best-known academy of magic.

### **Conjuration**

> At **The Acadamae**, Korvosa's premier magical institute for the instruction of specialist wizards, conjuration is favored over the other eight schools of study and is a required component of every student's final examinations.
>
> Conjurers, especially if they are also diabolists, find considerable favor in **Cheliax**. Living in a country where the state religion is the worship of Asmodeus, Cheliax's citizens tend to respect all arcane spellcasters due to their assumed connections to Hell.
>
> Other groups known to deal with conjuration include the opposing B**lackfire Adepts** and **Riftwardens**, the **Irriseni Bloodstone Conservatory**, genie binders, **Hellknights**, Nidalese shadowcallers, and Osirian mages.

### **Divination**

> Diviners are often found in the company of leaders and the military, as their magics allow them to glean information about enemies and discover the presence of spies, assassins, or plots against them. **Pharasma**, the goddess of fate and prophecy, is the patron of diviners.
>
> With the advent of the **Age of Lost Omens** (death of Aroden) over a century ago, the reputation of diviners and soothsayers has been diminished.

### **Enchantment**

> **Elven** minds seem to be particularly resistant to enchantment magics. The god **Asmodeus** is associated with enchantments and enchanters of all kinds, and is often worshiped by the less wholesome ones.

### **Evocation**

> At the premier arcane school of Varisia, **the Acadamae**, evocation is the second-most popular specialization after conjuration.

### Illusion

> The lesser-known goddess **Sivanah**, also known as **the Seventh Veil**, is considered the patron deity of illusion magics, using it to cleverly conceal her own appearance under layers of obfuscation. Illusionists can be found as priests of her church, although those with different personal or philosophical outlooks can also be found among the clergy of **Calistria** or **Norgorber**.

### Necromancy

> Some of the most well-known necromancers the world has ever known were undead creatures themselves, such as the archmage **Geb**, and the dreaded lich known as the **Whispering Tyrant**. The goddess **Urgathoa** is the patron deity of many necromancers, although some also worship the lesser-known d**emon lord Orcus**.
>
> Although they can be found throughout the world, the arcane schools of the Garundi nation of Geb specialize in the teaching of necromancy. One of the most notable is the **Ebon Mausoleum** in the capital, **Mechitar**.

### Transmutation

> Among the **Varisian** people, this type of magic is known as "avaria"
>
> The ice mages of **Irrisen** are known to be focus largely on transmutation spells, especially those that deal with manipulating all forms of water.
>
> The wizards of the land of **Nex** are said to have a strong preference for this form of magic.

### Other Academies

- **Arcanamirium** The largest and most respected school of arcane magic in the
  Inner Sea region, established by exiled arclords of Nex, focuses
  on the study of **practical magic**. Location **Absalom**.
- **Magaambya** Founded by legendary wizard Old-Mage Jatembe, this is the oldest surviving and still operating academy in the Inner Sea region. Location **Nantambu** (Mwangi Expanse).

### Spellcaster Guilds

- **Kintargo Opera House** Growing swiftly and welcoming non-Chelish students, this Chelish opera house is building a dangerous reputation for fostering *free thinkers.* Location **Kintargo** (Cheliax).
- **Oenopion Fleshforges** Strange new soldiers are alchemically and magically constructed in the experimental laboratories of the Oenopion Fleshforges. Location **Oenopion** (Nex).
- **Poisoner’s Guild** One of Daggermark’s most powerful and notorious guilds, the Poisoner’s Guild is led by Tragshi the Herbalist. Location **Daggermark** (River Kingdoms).
- **The White Grotto** is the premier bardic college in Absalom, a guild where one can learn the arts of using magic to enhance all forms of entertainment. Location **Absalom**.

### Secret Societies

- **Citadel Enferac** The stronghold of the Hellknights of the Order of the Gate, Citadel Enferac is one of the primary locations at which Hellknight spellcasters (known as **signifers**) of all orders train. Location **Menador Mountains** (Cheliax).
- **The Harrowed Society** Based in the town of Galduria, the Harrowed Society uses the Twilight Academy as a sort of “ front” for their true purpose: to decipher the mysteries held in **harrow cards**, the traditional Varisian fortune-teller’s tools. The Harrowed Society believes that if these mysteries can be deciphered, the true secrets of reality can be learned. Location **Galduria** (Varisia).
- **Crimson Citadel** The Crimson Citadel is the headquarters of the **Red Mantis
  assassins**, deadly and mysterious killers who worship **Achaekek the Mantis God**. Location **Mediogalti Island**.

(References of academies, secret societies and guilds taken from [Inner Sea Magic](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8mfs?Pathfinder-Campaign-Setting-Inner-Sea-Magic).)

Comment: Perhaps you could trim down the quotes to just the relevant parts.

Comment: Nice! I was going to add all these major ones from the book but got lazy! :)

Comment: There is also Theumenexis College in Korvosa. It is a generalists school. :) https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Theumanexus_College

Answer (score 5):

Academies of Magic may be found all over Golarion. There is no way to cover all the potential locations but you will definitely find them in most all (if not all) major cities. If you really want specifics pick up a copy of Paizo's "Inner Sea Magic" which covers practically everything you'd ever need to know on the subject.

Comment: Maybe name two or three with a short description? Seems this answer is missing something.

Comment: @Mala How does it not answer the question? *“Would a wizard's college be something that every major city would have to at least a certain degree? **If not**…”* It covers the part of the question before “if not” just fine, so it's unclear why it should need to also answer the “if not” part.